# mysql group based on time intervals

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to query a table which is like

Table structure for table archive

```
|------
|Column|Type|Null|Default
|------
|//**id**//|int(11)|No|
|datetime|timestamp|No|CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
|gatewayid|int(11)|No|
|RSSI|float|No|
|distance|float|No|
|beaconid|int(11)|No|
== Dumping data for table archive

|1|2017-08-22 12:14:19|1|-65|36|1
|2|2017-08-22 12:14:19|2|-60|30|1
|3|2017-08-22 12:14:19|3|-60|30|1
|4|2017-08-22 12:14:19|1|-52|63|2
|5|2017-08-22 12:14:19|2|-36|33|2
|6|2017-08-22 12:14:19|3|-65|33|2
|7|2017-08-22 12:14:19|1|-69|66|3
|8|2017-08-22 12:14:19|2|-65|33|3
|9|2017-08-22 12:14:19|3|-66|33|3
|10|2017-08-22 12:16:09|1|-65|36|1
|11|2017-08-22 12:16:09|2|-60|30|1
|12|2017-08-22 12:16:09|3|-60|30|1
|13|2017-08-22 12:16:09|1|-52|63|2
|14|2017-08-22 12:16:09|2|-36|33|2
|15|2017-08-22 12:16:09|3|-65|33|2
|16|2017-08-22 12:16:09|1|-69|66|3
|17|2017-08-22 12:16:09|2|-65|33|3
|18|2017-08-22 12:16:09|3|-66|33|3
|19|2017-08-22 12:32:05|1|-65|36|1
|20|2017-08-22 12:32:05|2|-60|30|1
|21|2017-08-22 12:32:05|3|-60|30|1
|22|2017-08-22 12:32:05|1|-52|63|2
|23|2017-08-22 12:32:05|2|-36|33|2
|24|2017-08-22 12:32:05|3|-65|33|2
|25|2017-08-22 12:32:05|1|-69|66|3
```

I want to average `RSSI` values based on theses rules
- group based on gatewayid,beaconid and datetime
- the group by datetime should be in every 5 minutes for example

well in fact I want avrage RSSI values for rows which their beaconid and gatewayid are the same and they are added in a 5 minutes interval,
I have written this query

```
select DATE_ADD( '1900-01-01T00:00:00',INTERVAL 15+TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, '1900-01-01T00:00:00', datetime) minute),
      (sum(RSSI)/count(*)) as mean_rssi,
      (sum(distance)/count(*)) as mean_distance,
      beaconid,
      gatewayid 
from archive 
GROUP by DATE_ADD( '1900-01-01T00:00:00',INTERVAL 15+TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, '1900-01-01T00:00:00', datetime) minute),
         beaconid,
         gatewayid
```

Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8962a2/5) for create statement 
this query returns all rows without any  changes,where am I doing wrong?
thanks

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry Hi, Thanks for your comment, I've updated my question, can you pleas check it if it is ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query appears to be correct it's just that your data is unique on interval/beaconid/getewayid so it happens to return 'all' rows...

If I understand your data you probably want to `group by` 5 min intervals, and to get a value that is the same for every five min interval you may opt to just divide the timestamp by 300 seconds - something like:

```
select min(`datetime`) as `start`,
  (sum(RSSI)/count(*)) as mean_rssi,
  (sum(distance)/count(*)) as mean_distance,
  beaconid,
  gatewayid 
from archive 
group by UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime`) / 60*5,
  beaconid,
  gatewayid
```

also use sqlfiddle or rextester it is much easier to help you if you use those...

Comment: thanks very much, I think my own query returns the same as yours, I tried to use sqlfiddle but I faced errors because of my Internet connection